# Getting Rooms within my Area Plan, Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have created several AreaPlans in Revit and I need to get the rooms within those AreaPlans and sort them according to which AreaPlan they belong.

I am using Revit 2021 and VisualStudio 2019

A Code-Example would be of great help.

Thank you in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that since an `AreaPlan` is a type of `View`, then you are really asking for what `Room`s fall within the boundaries of an `Area`.  Check out this page:  https://jeremytammik.github.io/tbc/a/0810_room_in_area.htm